# PHP function does not execute

Tags: php

I am attempting to call a class function from address bar as follows:

```
http://localhost:82/spam_fetcher.php?rm=index
```

My script is:

```
  class Spam_fetcher{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['rm']) && method_exists('Spam_fetcher', $_GET['rm'])) {
            $view = new Spam_fetcher();
            $view->$_GET['rm']();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No such a function";
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'something';
    }
}
```

But index function does not execute. What do you guys think I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Wrong place: you didn't show your code & where did you call your method

Comment: What code is executing in your script?

Comment: You just *define* a class, there's nothing actually *instantiating* or calling it (as far as we can see).

Comment: I'd like to call index() and echo out 'something' what is your suggestion?

Comment: `$sf = new Spam_fetcher; $sf->index();`

Comment: without create a object of class how can you aspect output?

Comment: I thought that $view = new Spam_fetcher();
            $view->$_GET['rm'](); does it.

Comment: @curiozity, That will give you maximum number of nesting levels reached notices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Spam_fetcher{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['rm']) && method_exists($this, $_GET['rm'])) {
           $this->$_GET['rm']();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No such a function";
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'something';
    }
}

$view = new Spam_fetcher();
```

Comment: +1 , You should also explain the changes done on your code like adding $this , created a new instance, removed the `new Spam_fetcher();`.. etc.

Comment: `$this->$_GET['rm']();` possible code injection. Never ever do like this without checking user input first or at least escaping it.